# Employee Program. JAVA basics

Tags: java

I am writing a simple start-up java program. The problem I am facing is that the company name is not being added properly.

```
public class Company {
    public static BufferedReader br;
    public static BufferedReader br1;
    public static String numberOfCompanies;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CompanyDetails qw = new CompanyDetails();

        try{
            //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter number of companies: ");
            numberOfCompanies = br.readLine();
            int G = Integer.parseInt(numberOfCompanies);

            for (int i = 1; i <= G; i++) {
                qw = new CompanyDetails();
                System.out.println("Enter name of the company: ");
                String company = br1.readLine();
                qw.company(company, i);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= G; i++) {
            qw.companySummary(G);
            }
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   
}

class CompanyDetails {
    String company, name;
    public String input;
    public static BufferedReader br;
    public double iE;
    public static String numberOfCompanies;
    String nameOfCompany;
    String[] nameofCompany1 = new String[100];
    int ir,i,employee;
    ArrayList<String> bulk = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String[] company(String input, int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //ArrayList bulk = new ArrayList();
        //for(int ith = i; ith<= 2; i++){
        nameOfCompany = i+input;
        bulk.add(nameOfCompany);
        bulk.add(nameOfCompany);
    //  }
        return nameofCompany1;
    }

    public void employee(double d) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ir = (int)d;
    }

    public void companySummary(int G) {

        System.out.println("Number of companies: " + G);
        System.out.println("Name of company: " +bulk +" ");
        System.out.println("Number of employees: "+ir); 
    }   
}
```

The output I am getting is

[image]

Why aren't I getting 234 at the position 1 of the arraylist ??

Comment: You have a LOT of useless stuff in there...

Comment: what's the purpose of the bulk arraylist? why not just use nameOfCompany?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `CompanyDetails` object in each iteration of the loop, there by loosing your earlier object:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= G; i++) {
   qw = new CompanyDetails();
```

You are already creating an `CompanyDetails` object at the start of `main` method:

```
CompanyDetails qw = new CompanyDetails();
```

So you don't have to do it again in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String[] company(String input, int i) {

nameOfCompany = i+input;
bulk.add(nameOfCompany);
bulk.add(nameOfCompany); .// Why are you adding nameOfCompany twice .
return nameofCompany1;    //Why are you returning nameofCompany1 which is null here
```

}

```
 qw = new CompanyDetails();  //this line should be out of the loop.
```

Work on [Naming Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_conventions_%28programming%29).
Please provide more details on what you want to do and what output you expect .

Comment: I would like to make a simple program that should retrieve company values and then sort it out according to the number of employees and then print the result

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at code-snippet: `qw = new CompanyDetails();` is instantiated per loop.

It should be:

```
 qw = new CompanyDetails();
 for (int i = 1; i <= G; i++) {
  ...
 }
```

As @CodeBuzz pointed out : remove `bulk.add(nameOfCompany);` in `company()` method and also do not iterate the `qw.companySummary(G);` method.

Answer (score 1):

In your CompanyDetails class remove one line `bulk.add(nameOfCompany);` in the method `public String[] company(String input, int i)` and put `qw = new CompanyDetails();` outside of the for loop in you main method and it will work fine.

Main class

```
public class Company {
    public static BufferedReader br;
    public static BufferedReader br1;
    public static String numberOfCompanies;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CompanyDetails qw = new CompanyDetails();

        try{
            //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter number of companies: ");
            numberOfCompanies = br.readLine();
            int G = Integer.parseInt(numberOfCompanies);

            qw = new CompanyDetails();
            for (int i = 1; i <= G; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter name of the company: ");
                String company = br1.readLine();
                qw.company(company, i);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= G; i++) {
            qw.companySummary(G);
            }
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   
}
```

CompanyDetails class

```
class CompanyDetails {
    String company, name;
    public String input;
    public static BufferedReader br;
    public double iE;
    public static String numberOfCompanies;
    String nameOfCompany;
    String[] nameofCompany1 = new String[100];
    int ir,i,employee;
    ArrayList<String> bulk = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String[] company(String input, int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //ArrayList bulk = new ArrayList();
        //for(int ith = i; ith<= 2; i++){
        nameOfCompany = i+input;
        //bulk.add(nameOfCompany);
        bulk.add(nameOfCompany);
    //  }
        return nameofCompany1;
    }

    public void employee(double d) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ir = (int)d;
    }

    public void companySummary(int G) {

        System.out.println("Number of companies: " + G);
        System.out.println("Name of company: " +bulk +" ");
        System.out.println("Number of employees: "+ir); 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see your question has been well answered. I have one little remark I would like to add related to naming conventions. I would rename method `company` in the `CompanyDetails` class to `AddCompany` or `registerCompany` to make sure your readers understand the meaning of that method without having to go deep into its implementation details.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The program for retrieving Employee details is below:

```
package employee;
import java.util.*;

public class Employee

{

String name,  gender,address;

 int id;

float salary,da,hra,gross_pay;

public void getdata()

{  
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the name of employee");

name=in.next();

System.out.println("Enter the id of employee");

id=in.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Enter the gender of employee");

gender=in.next();

System.out.println("Enter the address of employee");

address=in.next();

 }

public void calc()

 {

 Scanner in= new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("enter the salary of employee");

salary=in.nextFloat();

da=salary*15/100;

 hra=salary*10/100;

gross_pay=salary+da+hra;

 }

 public void display()

 {  

System.out.println("Employee Details");

System.out.println("Employee name:"+name+" ");

System.out.println("Employee id:"+id+" ");

System.out.println("Employee gender:"+gender+" ");

System.out.println("Employee address:"+address+" ");

System.out.println("Employee salary:"+salary+" ");

System.out.println("da amount"+da+" ");

System.out.println("hra amount:"+hra+" ");

System.out.println("Gross_pay of employee:"+gross_pay+" ");

 }

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

Employee emp=new Employee();

emp.getdata();

emp.calc();

emp.display();

}

}
```

Output:

```
Enter the name of employee

Raju

Enter the id of employee

20

Enter the gender of employee

Male

Enter the address of employee

XYZ Street, India.

Enter the salary of employee

45000

Employee Details

Employee name:Raju 

Employee id:20 

Employee gender:Male 

Employee address:XYZ 

Employee salary:45000.0 

DA amount6750.0 

HRA amount:4500.0 

Gross_pay of employee:56250.0
```